# docker-compose can not reach swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have used following manual to install swarm on my machines **without** using docker-machine:
https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/
Now I want to use docker-compose to create cluster of containerised apps.
But can not get docker-compose to reach swarm.

EG: 
Following command give back result:

```
docker -H :4000 ps
```

but, docker-compose don't:

```
docker-compose -H my.IP.address:4000 ps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 61, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 113, in perform_command
  File "contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
  File "compose/cli/errors.py", line 56, in handle_connection_errors
TypeError: log_timeout_error() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
docker-compose returned -1
```

`docker-compose -H :4000 ps`  do not reach swarm either

Does anybody have idea what am I doing wrong?

There are some hints to set env variables for:

`DOCKER_HOST
DOCKER_CERT_PATH
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY`

But how to get DOCKER_CERT_PATH

Comment: pls edit your question to answer the following: Are the machines local or on cloud infrastructur? Did you set up certificates? Are you about to run these commands from the swarm master node or from somwhere else? Do you already have configured a discovery backend?

Comment: Hi, machines are local, but they are virtual created with KVM. They are in same network.
Commands are executed from swarm master node. For discovery I have used consul as described in manual mentioned above.

Certificates I have not set, could that be a problem?

Comment: ok try using `-H localhost:4000` or set `DOCKER_HOST` to `localhost:4000` it does the same

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help:

`[root@uxtest14 es-cluster]# docker-compose -H localhost:4000 ps
ERROR: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
....
....
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://localhost:4000/v1.21/containers/json?">http://localhost:4000/v1.21/containers/json?</a></p>`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not related to docker. I was running virtual machines behind proxy and variable no_proxy was not set.